# US Census Data using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with some info from the US CENSUS website. I am able to plot every state and the population, but I want to isolate just one state (UTAH) and I am having trouble with the code.

The code below is the data I want to chart and the configuration:
    content.loc[45:45, ['1910_POPULATION', '1920_POPULATION', 
    '1930_POPULATION', '1940_POPULATION', '1950_POPULATION', 
    '1960_POPULATION', '1970_POPULATION', '1980_POPULATION','1990_POPULATION', 
    '2000_POPULATION']]

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(content.[45:45], content.['1910_POPULATION', '1920_POPULATION', 
'1930_POPULATION', '1940_POPULATION', '1950_POPULATION', 
'1960_POPULATION', '1970_POPULATION', '1980_POPULATION','1990_POPULATION', 
'2000_POPULATION'])
plt.xlabel([45:45])
plt.ylabel('POPULATION')
plt.show()
```

ANy idea how I can fix this to plot a simple chart if the population growth using MATPLOTLIB?

Comment: Can you add what error you get? Also is `45` a valid row label of the data? And in the code above is `content.[45:45]` a typo?

Comment: 45:45 is the correct positioning for the state info I want. I just need to know how to plot a basic chart with data from a single state.

Comment: what structure is your data in?  can you give a snapshot?

Comment: You are having trouble? Which kind of trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(content.loc[45, ['1910_POPULATION', '1920_POPULATION', 
'1930_POPULATION', '1940_POPULATION', '1950_POPULATION', 
'1960_POPULATION', '1970_POPULATION', '1980_POPULATION','1990_POPULATION', 
'2000_POPULATION']])
plt.xlabel([45:45])
plt.ylabel('POPULATION')
plt.show()
```